# Get attributes of child inputs of elements in .each() inside another .each()

Tags: jquery

my first post here. I'm not new to JQuery, but I find complex coding quite difficult (naturally!). I will explain my problem as clearly as possible. I'm using **elgg** so some code here will be elgg specific. That will not be an issue.

I'm creating a page that allows my users to add questions to something. They can add questions using the following method:

```
echo "<div id='ques_holder'>";
echo "<table><tr><td style='width:380px;padding-right:10px;'>";
    echo "<b>Question:</b> ";
    echo elgg_view("input/text", array('internalname' => 'ques_','internalid' => 'ques_'));
echo "</td><td style='width:90px;'>";
    echo "<b>Answer:</b> ";
    echo elgg_view("input/pulldown", array('internalname' => 'ans_','internalid' => 'ans_', 'options_values' => array('true' => 'True', 'false' => 'False')));
echo "</td></tr></table>";
echo "</div>";
```

I now want to make it possible to add more than one question at a time so I use the following cloning code to accomplish this:

```
var quescount = 0;

function add_question() {
quescount++;
var clone = $("#ques_holder").clone(false);
$("*", clone).add(clone).each(function() {
    if (this.id) {
        this.id = this.id + quescount;
    }
    if (this.name) {
        this.name = this.name + quescount;
    }
});
$("#interact_input_questions_adder").append(clone);
}
```

This is all working fine. New questions are added and their ids and names are updated with a number (quescount) as well as their child elements as well. The problem comes with the following part. **I'm trying to get all the input names and values together for sending via ajax to a php file.** This is where my code is breaking. I was trying a double .each() call (one inside the other), but something in my coding isn't working. The code is below:

```
function save_questions(){
    var qrange = [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12,13,14,15,16,17,18,19,20];
    var activity = "<?php echo $activity;?>";
    datastr = "&activity=" + activity;
    jQuery.each(qrange , function(index,value){
        $("#ques_holder"+value).find('input').each(function(){
            datastr += $(this).attr('name');
        });
    });
    alert(datastr);
}
```

**Things to Consider**
The types of inputs coming in could change each time (the one I gave is just one example)
The elgg coding is not breaking things
The **qrange** array is simply to restrict the number of questions (which I haven't put into the add_question() function just yet)

I guess what I'm wondering is...can you do a .each() inside a jQuery.each(), and according to my coding, **how can I get the names of all those inputs found inside those each calls?**

Any help much appreciated. Don't feel shy to ridicule me for my ugly coding, I taught myself through trial and error from sites like stackoverflow. ;)

**EDIT**: after severe face-palming I realised the mistake was an oversight of not using an "onclick" when I should be. The final stuff is as follows and was actually supplied by **RightSaidFred** who for some reason then removed his answer.

```
function save_questions(){
    var qrange = [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12,13,14,15,16,17,18,19,20];
    var activity = "<?php echo $vars['activity'];?>";
    datastr = "&activity=" + activity;
    jQuery.each(qrange , function(index,value){
        $("#ques_holder"+value).find('input').each(function(input_idx, input){
            datastr += "&" + $(input).attr('name') + "=" + $(input).attr('value');
        });
    });
    alert(datastr);
}
```

Comment: And how is your code breaking? What is the content of `datastr`? That is an important detail :). `.each()` inside `$.each()` is working - see [this fiddle](http://jsbin.com/osojil/edit#javascript,live).

Comment: What does "something in my coding isn't working" mean?  What do you want to happen and what is actually happening instead?

Comment: **face palm** - terrible rookie mistake of using older code. I previously had the button to "save questions" set with an id, but then changed the jQuery to a function so needed an onclick. Alerts are now coming up as they should with the correct data. The below method from **maxijb** also solves the problem so I will mark it as correct and add my finalized code to the question. Sorry for being dumb, it's too early in the morning here!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Why don't you put a class to all the 'ques_holder' divs, for example

```
  <div id='ques_holder' class='holder'>
```

Then, you just have to do one each to grab all the inputs

```
 $("div.holder input").each(function() {
      var name = $(this).attr('name'); // if you need the name
      var val = $(this).val();   // if you need the value
      var parent = $(this).closest('div.holder').attr('id'); // if you need to know the parent number
});
```

Comment: thanks I'm just testing at the moment. I'm alerting the results, but the alert is not showing, so I'm just checking if there is something else causing that to happen.I'll post back with further results of testing.

Comment: This method works well in general, although for my specific case it doesn't. The reason for this is because my original div block for cloning is hidden and should not be included in the datastr. (something I failed to mention)

Comment: Put an unique id _ques_holder_ to the hidden block that should't be included. Call it like this... $("div.holder:not(#ques_holder) input").each(...

Comment: thanks your code is extremely concise compared to mine and I will use it for future reference. I set your answer as accepted. I'd vote it up but I've got no reputation :(, so +1